# proving the sum is direct.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem goes this way:

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers that $k<n$. Let $_F V$be a vector space of dimension $n$. Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\{w_1,...,w_k\}$ is a basis for $W$. If $\{w_1,...,w_k,w_{k+1},...,w_n \}$ is a basis for $V$, show that $V=W \bigoplus U$, where $U = \text{span}\{w_{k+1},...,w_n \}$.

My goal is to show that dim$(W \cap U)=0$? am I right? but I don't have any idea on how. thanks.

Comment: Suppose the intersection is non trivial. What does this mean?? U should be able to get to contradiction easily this way

Answer (score 0):

As the comment hints:

$$x\in W\cap U\implies x=\sum_{i=1}^k a_iw_i=\sum_{i=k+1}^n (-a_i)w_i\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb F\implies$$

$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^na_iw_i=0\,.\;\;\text{But}\;\;\{w_1,...,w_n\} \;\;\text{is a basis, so...}$$

Comment: So all $a_i =0$ this x is just the zero vector?

Comment: @mogs Indeed so.